# Teradata Error 2679 when loading text file into table using MLoad

Tags: teradata, mload

I have a problem with loading my data into teradata table using MLoad. I have a text file with a data which is an output from SQL query.

```
851|73214|2019-01-03|2019-01-03|98.081270|RFF|249872083.40
854|73215|2019-01-03|2019-01-03|98.081270|RFF|355015298.0400
881|96634|2017-05-22|2017-05-22|97.697560|RFF|-6961747.270
```

and I'm trying to load this data using this mld file:

```
.LOGTABLE dss.load_DEALS7_log;
.RUN FILE "C:\PASS.TXT";

RELEASE MLOAD dss.DEALS;

drop table dss.DEALS;
create multiset table dss.DEALS
(
FILE_ROWNUM INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE -2147483647 MAXVALUE 100000000 NO CYCLE),
DEAL INTEGER,
EFFECT_DATE VARCHAR(80),
MAT_DATE VARCHAR(80),
CON DECIMAL(28,12),
C_CODE VARCHAR(80),
QUALITY DECIMAL(19,4),


LOAD_DTE DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD'
)primary index(FILE_ROWNUM);

.BEGIN MLOAD TABLES dss.DEALS SESSIONS 2;
.LAYOUT FILE;
.FIELD DEAL * VARCHAR(80);
.FIELD EFFECT_DATE * VARCHAR(80);
.FIELD MAT_DATE * VARCHAR(80);
.FIELD CON * VARCHAR(80);
.FIELD C_CODE * VARCHAR(80);
.FIELD QUALITY * VARCHAR(80);


.DML LABEL LOAD;

INSERT INTO dss.DEALS VALUES
('',
:DEAL,
:EFFECT_DATE,
:MAT_DATE,
:CON,
:C_CODE,
:QUALITY,

CURRENT_DATE
);

.IMPORT 
 INFILE  "C:\deals.txt"
 LAYOUT FILE
 format VARTEXT '|' DISPLAY ERRORS NOSTOP
 APPLY LOAD

 ;
.END MLOAD;
.LOGOFF;
```

The problem is that the final table is empty and every row is in dss.ET_DEALS table with ErrorCode 2679. I know that the ErrorField is QUALITY, but I don't know why It won't load. The data seems alright. Teradata docs say - "This error occurs when the user submits a numeric-to-character conversion with an illegal format, or when, in converting characters to numeric, either the data or the format contains a bad character." At first I thought That It's because of negative numbers, but then there should only be few rows and not whole input data in ET table. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: QUALITY is field #6 and 'RFF' cabn't be converted to a decimal. The 1st field in the input file is not matched in the LAYOUT.

Comment: I'm super lazy about mload. I would just dump this into a staging table with all the columns defined as varchar, and I would skip the the autoincrement column.  I would handle the rest of it using SQL to load to the final table.

Comment: Additionally, your sample file has 7 columns, not 6.

Comment: @Andrew: Your approach is way better :-) Additionally using FastLoad instead of MLoad (or TPT LOAD instead of legacy FL)

Comment: @Andrew Ok. That makes sense. So I guess that I only need to add the ID column for FILE_ROWNUM in my layout and insert and It should run. Did I get it right ? I'll probably rebuild this in some time, but there are like 30 MLoad files and all are constructed like this. That's the beauty of overtaking someone's tasks. ;)

Comment: Start the layout with `.FILLER * VARCHAR(80);` to skip FILE_ROWNUM in the input.

Comment: @dnoeth I added the line that you gave me, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Still the same error 2679 for QUALITY? Did you add the FILLER as 1st field?

Comment: @dnoeth Yeah I added It like this .BEGIN MLOAD TABLES dss.DEALS SESSIONS 2;
.LAYOUT FILE; .FILLER * VARCHAR(80);
.FIELD DEAL * VARCHAR(80); and I still get the same error

Comment: Not sure you can MLOAD a table where the PI is GENERATED ALWAYS. Generally MLOAD requires the client to supply the PI values. Not sure why 2679 though. You could try using a column name list in the INSERT instead of positional form.

Comment: @Fred the weird thing is that this is the only mload that doesn't work and others are 1:1 to this. The only thing that is different between them are column names. I checked the input data few times and everything seems also fine. It's really weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted and crated the tables from ground up and also added
`.FILLER * VARCHAR(80);`
in my mld file and It works fine.